# Hamming distance and hamming weight

Tags: coding-theory

I am stuck on a proof:

> Let $x$ and $y$ be any two vectors in $F_q.$  Show that $wt(x+y)>= |wt(y) - wt(x)|$, where wt(.) denotes the hamming weight.

Now I know that $wt(x+y)$ is the cardinality of all non-zero indices of x+y,

I need help in showing mathematically how
   $wt(x+y) >= |wt(y) - wt(x)|$

If anyone could suggest that would be great! thank you

Comment: "Now I know that wt(x+y) is the cardinality of all the places where x and y differs" -> isn't it only for $q=2$?

Comment: no not really. hamming weight just basically just the number of non zero coordinates .

Comment: So if $x=(1,1,1)=y$ in $\mathbb{F}_5$, we have $x+y=(2,2,2)$ and $wt(x+y) =3$, while $x=y$. Don't we?

Comment: example:
 let x= {2,3,5,4,0}     q=6
      y= {5,3,1,1,2}
wt(x)=4
wt(y)=5
wt(x+y)=4 (since in the second position xi=yi=3, so they cancel out)

Comment: You did use the convenient  fact that $3+3=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_6$. This is not the case that $a+b=0$ whenever $a= b$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Well, again I can't see why "wt(x+y) is the cardinality of all the places where x and y differs" holds -- cf. my second comment, where you have weight 3 for $x+y$ in spite of the fact that they differ in $0$ places.

Comment: Yes I can understand the theory but i have to show it for a general case in a q-ary field. that is what i am getting stuck at a little bit. because examples wont suffice the general proof...

Comment: isnt that how we calculate hamming weights between two codewords. number of non-zero coordinates in (x+y) ?

Comment: Yes, the Hamming weight of $x+y$ is, by definition, the number of non-zero coordinates of $x+y$. But it is **not** equal to "the cardinality of all the places where x and y differs" in general. It's not about proving by example: it's about what you used at the beginning of your argument being false.

Comment: okay i see your justification now. cardinality is appropriate in the binary field modulo 2 yes.

Comment: @ClementC.  $\mathbb F_6$? Isn't $q$ in $\mathbb F_q$ supposed to be a prime or a prime power?

Comment: @DilipSarwate That was not my example, but the OP's. Mine was with $q=5$.